# How to uninstall crictl completely

Tags: crictl

I was trying to uninstall crictl version 1.26.0, so that I could upgrade to version 1.27.0.
`

I removed the executable from /usr/bin and tried to install again, However the docs have changed and are copying the file to /usr/local/bin after unzipping the tar file. However, I still get the error `bash: /bin/crictl: No such file or directory meaning that it is still searching for the executable inside /usr/bin. How should I overwrite this behavior?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.